# Excel VBA Changing text inside shapes based off a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have made a large diagram of made by shapes with numbers stored inside as text and need to change the "old" numbers to a "new" range of numbers. On each of the 20 sheets there are circles, Rectangles, Left Arrows and Right Arrows. The old range of numbers are stored on a separate spreadsheet in the Column "A" and need to be changed to the numbers listed in Column "B" (as in A1 to B1).

What would a VBA method to change the old text inside the Shapes to the new correct text based off of a new range of numbers? Is it possible to write a script that changes the values in the entire WorkBook?

My incorrect way of thinking is to:
1. Search inside the diagram to find the various shapes.
2. Get the text inside each shape.
3. Compare the text with the spreadsheet with the old numbers.
4. Insert the new number.
5. Move onto the next shape.

Comment: Won't help now, but going forward... did you know that you can link the text in a shape to a cell? Once that is setup, all you need to do is update the cells to change the text in all the shapes!

Comment: I did not know that. I am relatively new to VBA and am still learning my way around the program. I will look into that thanks!

Comment: Sure, but it has nothing to do with VBA. To link the text, you use the formula bar, just like as if the shape were a cell, and you enter a simple formula in the formula bar, like:  `=A1` and then whatever value is in cell A1 will display in the shape as text.

Comment: But like most things from the Excel user interface, this linking can be done in VBA as well.

Answer (score 0):

Put a value in **A1** and say we already have a Shape:

[image]

Running this:

```
Sub LinkCellToShape()
   Dim sh As Shape
   Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
   sh.DrawingObject.Formula = "=A1"
End Sub
```

will link the text in the shape to the value in the cell.  You could also use:

```
sh.OLEFormat.Object.formula = "=A1"
```